# Can regex be used to find this pattern?

Tags: regex

I need to parse a large amount of data in a log file, ideally I can do this by splitting the file into a list where each entry in the list is an individual entry in the log.

Every time a log entry is made it is prefixed with a string following this pattern:

"4404: 21:42:07.433 - After this point there could be anything (including new line characters and such). However, as soon as the prefix repeats that indicates a new log entry."

4404 Can be any number, but is always then followed by a :.
21:42:07.433 is the 21 hours 42 mins 7 seconds 433 milliseconds.

I don't know much about regex, but is it possible to identify this pattern using it?

I figured something like this would work...

"*: [0-24]:[0:60]:[0:60].[0-1000] - *"

However, it just throws an exception and I fear I'm not on the right track at all.

```
List<string> split_content = Regex.Matches(file_content, @"*: [0-24]:[0:60]:[0:60].[0-1000] - *").Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Value).ToList();
```

Comment: What you have is more a pseudo pattern. Neither regex, nor glob. Please provide a very concise example of the log file.

Comment: In particular regex handles characters and don't understand the concept of number : you can't say "a number between 0 and 24", you need to say something like "a string whose first character is between '0' and '2' and the second between '0' and '9'". Your current `[0-24]` is parsed as "a character between 0 and 2, or 4"

Comment: Try [`\d+: (?:[01]\d|2[0-3]):[0-6]\d:[0-6]\d.\d{3}`](https://regex101.com/r/96zUwC/1)?

Comment: First of all, how are you reading the log? Line by line, or can you load it all into memory?

Answer (score 1):

The following expression would split a string according to your pattern:

```
\d+: \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d{3}
```

Add a `^` in the beginning if your delimiting string always starts a line (and use the `m` flag for regex). Capturing the log chunks with a regex would be more elaborate, I'd suggest just splitting (with `Regex.Split`) if you have your log content in the memory all at once.